# Precautions to tacken during reducing the size of ibdata file in master slave replication set up

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mysql-5.5

My ibdata file size is increasing in mysql5.5 version server and it has been set up with the  master-slave replication. Server contains 6 databases. What are the precautions to be taken during the process of reducing the size of ibdata file in an master slave replication setup when compared to normal server. I am using the Mysql 5.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

> My ibdata file size is increasing in mysql5.5 version server and it has been set up with the  master-slave replication. Server contains 6 databases. What are the precautions to be taken during the process of reducing the size of ibdata file in an master slave replication setup when compared to normal server.

They are the same precautions for both situations.

- Use a separate file per table, by including

  ```
  innodb_file_per_table
  ```

  in your `my.ini` file (note there is no `=` or value)
- Use `ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=INNODB` to change existing tables to single file format
- Use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` to reclaim space as needed.

Comment: Like we need to stop the replication and continue the process

Comment: No you don't actually, but you need to restart your MySQL service locally to get the `innodb_file_per_table` change into effect.